# If intersection of cuboid and surface is regular hexagon, cuboid is a cube.

Tags: geometry

> Intersection of right-angled parallelepiped (cuboid) and a surface is regular hexagon. Prove that the parallelepiped is actually a cube.

It's somehow obvious to me that it has to be *regular* cuboid (=cube) if the intersection is a *regular* hexagon, but I need formal proof.

Comment: In the case of a cube, do you know how the intersection actually occurs? That might give you some hints as to why the side lengths must be the same.

Comment: Hexagon that comes out as intersection of surface and  cube doesn't actually have to be regular, right?

Comment: Yes, what I meant is, given a cube, do you know how to slice it to get a regular hexagon?

Comment: Sides of hexagon have to be $a\sqrt2/2$ if $a$ is side of cube.